# driver for IR led board

Tags: driver, infrared, led-driver

I'm installing a cheap IR led board like [this](https://es.aliexpress.com/store/product/MOOL-CCTV-Camera-10Mil-90-Degree-Red-5mm-24-LED-Bulb-IR-Infrared-Lamp-Board/2969058_32828928742.html?spm=a219c.search0104.3.8.29b97497T2ClRo&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10547_319_10891_317_10548_10696_10084_453_454_10083_10618_10307_10820_10821_10301_10303_537_536_10059_10884_10887_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_56,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=ba257869-496d-440e-8708-52da74e95d07-1&algo_pvid=ba257869-496d-440e-8708-52da74e95d07&transAbTest=ae803_5).

Do they need any kind of driver? Or just a 12V power supply switched with a relay (to power on/off) If so, is there any kind of consideration I need for the relay?

(I'm controlling the thing from a raspberry pi keeping power source separated)

Comment: oh wow, did not noticed it wasnt public. Im updating the link. Thanks for pointing out. As for the relay you are right. A relay for switching on and of the led's from a gpio on the Pi .

Comment: That link will be out of date as soon as the store decides to sell some other variant, and then this question will no longer make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the listing it says:

> Tensión: DC 12 V

Which means: Voltage: DC 12 V

Which means you need to supply 12 V to this board. Unfortunately no current consumption is mentioned, my educated guess is that this board will consume less than 200 mA so any supply that can output 12 V with 0.5 A (or more) will suffice.

Instead of using only a relay I advise you to get a relay **module** designed to switch LEDs etc on/off from an RPi (or Arduino). Such a module will contain the relay but also a transistor which is needed to operate the relay. An RPi by itself isn't suitable to drive a relay directly. I recommend a module like [this one](https://es.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-Shipping-1PCS-5V-low-level-trigger-One-1-Channel-Relay-Module-interface-Board-Shield-For/1962508_32519570562.html?spm=a219c.search0604.3.49.456e4aca3XQCoG&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10843_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_453_10084_454_10083_10103_10618_10304_10307_10820_10301_10821_537_536,searchweb201603_80,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=bf365ccf-345a-43db-9a6d-059ebc63a65c-10&algo_pvid=bf365ccf-345a-43db-9a6d-059ebc63a65c&transAbTest=ae803_5):

[image]

Comment: yeah! I've used those in the past. So easy. So for the powering of the board no driver is needed? Just ACDC providing 12V 0.5+A straight to the board and this relay in between the + wire AFTER the transformer. we agree ?

Comment: hi, I noticed there is an LDR in the board among the leds .. the only reason for it to be there would be that the board automatically switches on-off, could it be ??